# How do I install Mobile Media converter?

Tags: software-installation

From where can I download Mobile Media converter for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5):

You can download [Mobile Media Converter](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.htm) from their site. This is a [link to their download page for Ubuntu packages](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverterUbuntu.htm). All their source code and bug tracking is done via [their LaunchPad page [image: LP]](https://launchpad.net/mmediac) though it doesn't appear they have a PPA setup yet.

Comment: thanks! Unfortunately the file I wanted to convert (.amr) was not recognized. I'm using the ffmpeg -i command line